# SWT on OS X: unified toolbar?

Tags: java, macos, swt, toolbar

Does SWT support OS-X-specific [unified toolbars](http://exploding-pixels.com/google_code/promo/UnifiedToolBar-promo.png) or [button bars](http://exploding-pixels.com/google_code/promo/BottomBar-promo.png)?

Comment: Not within SWT itself, but there's a project that has a number of nice OS X controls. I've been Googling and Googling, but I can't find where I saw it. I might have a copy on my work laptop; I'll let you know Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unified toolbar: according to [this Eclipse issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=222859), it should be implemented since version 3.7M3.